# Is there any good choice than propery file to store constants?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my Selenium + Java tests, I've lot of configuration data which are constants. Instead of storing them in test files, I found, it's better to store them in `.properties` file. I used it and found interesting. Is this the good way I've chosen or should I choose something else to store constants.

Constants are like :

```
baseUrl=http://www.abc.com
userName=abc
password=def
browserName=ff
.
.
.
```

Comment: Are those constants used in java program?

Comment: Why you cannot make final class with static final variables?

Comment: I just want to keep constant data separated at one place. So, is there any better choice than `.properties` file or this one is better? Just want to confirm.

Comment: Umm if you want to change those constants often then it's a good practice.

Comment: Otherwise you could make a `Constants` class which contains your static final vars.

Comment: Thanks @The amateur programmer! Actually, some of data is likely to change as tests, features, requirements will change.

Comment: If you want to use a `.properties` file you should adhere to the [`property` format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties) that usually involves `key` an `value`, either `key=value`, `key:value` or as the [German version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties)  suggests also (and fairly ambiguously) `key value`. Using just values as you put it would involve to write your own parser, no?

Comment: @Patru, thanks! and yes I know how to write `.properties` file. In the question, I just mentioned keys. Anyway, I'll update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties files are useful when data might change in feature (so you can update the values without recompiling whole code.)
 If your values are not going to change you can make them static final variable.